# How to make part of inner HTML bold when creating new element - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I want to make part of inner HTML bold when creating new tag, like this:

```
var movieTitle = "Potato";
var words = "Movie " + movieTitle.bold() + "is great";

var list = document.getElementById("ulList");
var newLI = document.createElement('li');

newLI.innerHTML = words;
list.appendChild(newLI);
```

**Output of this is :** Movie **Potato** is great

**Now my question is, can I make something like this without using innerHTML?**

*I already tried this with createTextNode() but this function transforms everything to text including html so I got result: Movie <"b">Potato<"/b"> is great*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer does not use the `innerHTML` property and treats the variable `movieTitle` as plain text.

```js
let movieTitle = "Potato"
let listItemElement = document.createElement("li")
listItemElement.textContent = "The movie "
let movieTitleElement = document.createElement("b")
movieTitleElement.textContent = movieTitle
listItemElement.appendChild(movieTitleElement)
listItemElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" is great"))
document.getElementById("ulList").appendChild(listItemElement)
```

```html
<ul id="ulList"></ul>
```

Comment: This sounds strange: Create a html tag and add the created text to it. But it works! But if I have two strings and want to have bold just one?                         a.textContent = \`<b>${dateString}</b> | ${bodystr}\`. Date should be bold, but body not.